# How to LRU-cache numerous objects made of C++ STL heavy structures?

Tags: c++, caching, stl, redis, lru

I have big C++/STL data structures (myStructType) with imbricated lists and maps. I have many objects of this type I want to LRU-cache with a key. I can reload objects from disk when needed. Moreover, it has to be shared in a multiprocessing high performance application running on a BSD plateform.

I can see several solutions:

1. I can consider a life-time sorted list of `pair<size_t lifeTime, myStructType v>` plus a map to o(1) access the index of the desired object in the list from its key, I can use shm and mmap to store everything, and a lock to manage access (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836863/shared-memory-or-mmap-linux-c-c-ipc)).
2. I can use a redis server configured for LRU, and redesign my data structures to redis key/value and key/lists pairs.
3. I can use a redis server configured for LRU, and serialise my data structures (myStructType) to have a simple key/value to manage with redis.

There may be other solutions of course. How would you do that, or better, how have you successfully done that, keeping in mind high performance ?

In addition, I would like to avoid heavy dependencies like Boost.

Answer (score 2):

I actually built caches (not only LRU) recently.

Options 2 and 3 are quite likely not faster than re-reading from disk. That's effectively no cache at all. Also, this would be a far heavier dependency than Boost.

Option 1 can be challenging. For instance, you suggest "a lock". That would be quite a contended lock, as it must protect each and every lifetime update, plus all LRU operations. Since your objects are already heavy, it may be worthwhile to have a unique lock per object. There are intermediate variants of this solution, where there is more than one lock, but also more than one object per lock. (You still need a key to protect the whole map, but that's for replacement only)

You can also consider if you really need strict LRU. That strategy assumes that the chances of an object being reused decreases over time. If that's not actually true, random replacement is just as good. You can also consider evicting more than one element at a time. One of the challenges is that when an element needs removing, it would be so from all threads, but it's sufficient if one thread removes it. That's why a batch removal helps: if a thread tries to take a lock for batch removal and it fails, it can continue under the assumption that the cache will have free space soon.

One quick win is to not update the LRU time of the last used element. It was already the newest, making it any newer won't help. This of course only has an effect if you often use that element quickly again, but (as noted above) otherwise you'd just use random eviction.

Comment: You did not address one important point: the OP mentioned his app was multi-process. Using shared memory to store STL like containers is not trivial. That's probably why he proposed external caching with Redis. A local cache per process would waste memory, but is probably much easier to implement.

Comment: @DidierSpezia: `redis` can't store STL objects either. And storing "STL-like" containers in shared memory is in fact not that hard. It's just that the Standard containers such as `std::vector` don't work well in shared memory.

Comment: I did not say that using Redis was better. But the OP already needs a serialization format to store things on disks, so it could use the same to store things in Redis. 10 years ago, we worked on an in-memory graph database, and developed a set of STL containers for shared memory (vector, map, list, etc ...). It was awkward and error prone. I would not recommend it. Now, boost::interprocess offers such capabilities ...

Comment: If "Options 2 and 3 are quite likely not faster than re-reading from disk" then I won't use redis. But I am surprised since disk access is replaced by RAM access. I have to precise that my shared objects won't be modified after being created. So can I assume in that case that STL vectors work well in shared memory ? Yes, I need already a serialisation format to store objects on disk, but my priority is performance. So, I will have a look at boost interprocess. Any other hint is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @lalebarde: If you don't have redis, but you have the same amount of RAM, then those diskfiles will be cached in RAM. And that diskcache is probably a well-tested LRU cache.

Comment: Having reviewed the boost inter process communication library with its managed_shared_memory, it looks like it is the best solution. I will make some tests. Thanks a lot for your help.